# Set the dropdown value on back button getting loaded from server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a page with 4 dropdowns.When I select the first dropdown there is a Ajax call will filter the other 3 dropdowns data, and click on submit button to display the second page.Now when I click on back button of browser the dropdowns in the first page has to retain the previous filled in data. only first dropdown is retaining the data, other 3 dropdowns are not populating the previously selected data.For this I am setting the cookie on click of form submit as follows:

```
this.SetCookieForPriceGuide = function () {
        document.cookie = "VehicleMake=" + $("#VehicleMake").val();
        document.cookie = "VehicleYear=" + $("#VehicleYear").val();
        document.cookie = "VehicleModel=" + $("#VehicleModel").val();
        document.cookie = "VehicleDamage=" + $("#VehicleDamage").val();

    };
```

SetCookieForPriceGuide in the button click event and on the back button the load function being called and there I am trying to set the dropdowns values as follows

```
this.load = function () {
        var VehicleYear = getCookie("VehicleYear");
        var VehicleMake = getCookie("VehicleMake");
        var VehicleModel = getCookie("VehicleModel");
        var VehicleDamage = getCookie("VehicleDamage");
}
```

getCookie method is as follows:

```
function getCookie(cookieValue) {
    var textValue = cookieValue + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(textValue) == 0) {
            return c.substring(textValue.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Back button what? Your application back button or browser back button. Please be more specific in describing your issue.

Comment: Is your getCookie(cookieValue) method returning accurate values in load method?

Comment: @Prakash I have already said in the question pls read carefully..and Yes the method returning accurate value

Comment: You have just written "on the back button", not specific back button!

Comment: So, you have just issue with the setting the value, right?

Comment: "on back button of browser"...

Comment: Set value of drop-downs on DOMContentLoaded rather than onload.

Comment: Yes..the only issue for setting the Previously selected value...

Comment: In that case the AJAX calling is stopped...

Comment: Probably, you will observe issue with finding dropdown(s) element, when setting its value on onload event.

Comment: Now on Dropdown the server call is being stopped..that should be same as Previous right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93996/discussion-between-parkash-kumar-and-santyessac).

Answer (score 1):

You can set selected value of dropdown(s) as following:

```
this.load = function () {
    setSelectedValue('ddl_VehicleYearId', getCookie("VehicleYear"), 'defaultValue');
    setSelectedValue('ddl_VehicleMakeId', getCookie("VehicleMake") 'defaultValue');
    setSelectedValue('ddl_VehicleModelId', getCookie("VehicleModel") 'defaultValue');
    setSelectedValue('ddl_VehicleDamageId', getCookie("VehicleDamage") 'defaultValue');
}

function setSelectedValue(dropdownId, cookieValue, defaultValue){
    var element = document.getElementById(dropdownId);
    if(cookieValue) // If cookie has value
        element.value = cookieValue;
    else    // set default value
        element.value = defaultValue;
}
```